# Unable to import .js file in RN Typescript project

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, npm, npm-publish

I have a file called Http.js in a module:

```
export default class Http {
    //stuff
}
```

I can access this class from a typescript project as follows:

```
import Http from 'myproject.core/services/Http';
```

I recently published the module containing this class to **npm** and after installing it in the same typescript project, i can nolonger access this class.

Is there a way i should be doing things to make this class accessible if published via npm?

Comment: Does the published project work in other project (e.g. in JS projects) and only does not work in this TS project?

Comment: It works when imported from another .js file or if i change the module file from .js to .ts